# Downloaded excel file not opening in newer office excel versions

Tags: javascript, excel

Downloaded excel file with extension .xlsx is not opening in microsoft excel.
Following code I have written to convert the response which is not working,

```
     response.onSuccess = function(data,status,header) {
            if (!data || data == '') {
                return;
            }
            var file = new Blob([data], {
                type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            });
            FileSaver.saveAs(file, 'ExcelTemplate.xlsx');
```

Comment: Your Excel file has xls extension. It must be xlsx.

Comment: If I provide .xlsx extension that file is not at all opening, and if I provide .xls version it opens encoded response directly. So providing .xlsx will not solve the problem